# Run a hive script stored in a HDFS location

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to run a hive script (.hql file) stored in HDFS location (hdfs://nameservice1/user/neeraj) but I'm not able to find the correct command to execute it. Is there a way to run it directly from HDFS location instead of moving it to my /home/ location?

Comment: Don't think you can do that, and why would you want a script stored in HDFS?

Answer (score 3):

```
hive -f <(hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/my_script.sql)
```

**Demo**

```
cat>my_script.sql
select 1+1 as result;

hdfs dfs -put my_script.sql /tmp
```

---

```
hive -f <(hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/my_script.sql)

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
hive> select 1+1 as result;
OK
2
```